# Power supply design, Pi filter

Tags: power, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, schematics

I am designing a power supply circuit. Does anyone have any calculation formulas for resistor which we connect across inductor or capacitor?

I have attached a circuit with  highlighting a connections of resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZtRQh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: R2 is generally not needed but keep in mind how C2 will be discharged during development, production and service. R1 will limit the Q of the CLC filter. You should simulate it.

Comment: Thank you so much winny ,

Comment: can you have any article and any other details

Comment: for calculation of R1

Comment: Unless you find a rule of thumb, it's mainly down to a simulation of a transient case and how much Q/peak voltage/peak current you can tolerate in your design. There are plenty of power supplies with no R1 at all.

Comment: Depending on the voltages involved, a discharge resistor (R2 or R3) should be included for safety, but it only needs to be a relatively high value that will not significantly affect the operation of the filter.

Comment: @PeterJennings It’s after the rectifier so the plug will still be safe to touch after unplugging. It would be for safety of service personnel.

Comment: It's not just the plug, whilst you are developing / testing the power supply, you don't want to have capacitors that have retained any charge for you to accidentally touch. Particularly as it sounds as if you are rectifying the mains supply.

Comment: @PeterJennings
thank you so much for the response ,

Comment: And leave it in circuit once you have finished, you never know when you or someone else will have to do some maintenance at a later date.

Answer (score -3):

I use R = sqrt(L / C), thus 1uh and 1,000uF need sqrt(0.001) or about 0.03 ohms.

Your circuit, with 1uH and 1uF, needs sqrt(1/1) = 1 ohm, connected across Inductor.

You can derive this, using any resonant circuit formula with dampening resistor, and setting the Q to be 1, then solving for L/C or similar.

Consider 1 Henry and 1 Farad. The Fresonance is 0.16 Hz. Xl = Xc =   +-J1 ohm.
Using 1 ohm for the dampening resistor, the Q must be one.

Is Q of 1 what you wish?

Comment: I think this would make sense if r1 was in series with the inductor, not parallel to it. Not good advice for the givin circuit.